# Scala Typeclasses

Tags: scala, functional-programming, typeclass

I'm trying to implement simple type class pattern. It suppose to work similarly to scalaz's typeclasses. Unfortunately I can't get it to work. I have trait `Str`

```scala
trait Str[T] {
  def str(t: T): String
}

object Str {
  def apply[T](implicit instance: Str[T]) : Str[T] = instance
}
```

And in my and implicit instance of it.

```scala
object Temp extends App {

  implicit val intStr = new Str[Int] {
    def str(i: Int) = i.toString
  }

  1.str //error: value str is not a member of Int

}
```

I would appreciate any insight.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Str(1).str`? You were not defining an `implicit class`, just an `object` with `apply`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything you can do now is

```
Str[Int].str(1)
```

to use `1.str` you need to introduce implicit conversion.

You can for example use this approach:

```
implicit class StrOps[A](val self: A) extends AnyVal {
    def str(implicit S: Str[A]) = S.str(self)
}
```

Which gives:

```
scala> 1.str
res2: String = 1
```